# Is there a Linux equivalent of DllImport in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, c++, linux, .net-core

I am working on a .NET Core project. This should run on Linux without problems. However, I need to call a library that has been created with C++. Traditionally, C# developers do this with [DllImport&DllExport](https://blog.quickbird.uk/calling-c-from-net-core-759563bab75d).

However, I do not want to import or export dll's in a production environment. Over there it needs to run on Linux. Is there a Linux equivalent of DllImport/DllExport? [On Linux, so files are used instead of dll files](https://superuser.com/a/71408/599653). I am not smart when it comes to low level things so I look for a quick solution and a clear example. Something like an "SoImport"?

Comment: Do you try to use DllImport? As far as I know, .so or .dll is just an extension, so I think DllImport will do the job

Comment: DllImport works with any DLLs (dynamic linked libraries), including .so ones.

Comment: A dll is designed to run on a Windows PC.  Linux works ontop of the Windows Kernel and give windows UNIX functionality.  So any file that is compiled and outputs a dll file should run on both Windows and Linux.  You have to be careful because some dlls may require Net Library to be installed and some dlls may be compiled to work on 64 bit PCs.

Comment: @jdweng "Linux works ontop of the Windows Kernel and give windows UNIX functionality" - errrrrrrrrrr what? do you mean cygwin? or a VM?

Comment: @jdweng .Net core is not just a Windows thing, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x  Also Windows DLLs are not available to Linux apps running in the Linux subsystem, even on Windows.  These are ELF binaries and will be looking for shared libraries in .so format.  Windows _emulates_ the Linux kernel so that these binaries can run unmodified, see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/04/22/windows-subsystem-for-linux-overview/).

Comment: You can use DllImport to pinvoke an unmanaged library on Linux. However, first of all you need that library. Do you have it. You will need a Linux version.

Answer (score 12):

You can use .so file also in DllImport.

```
[DllImport ("libc.so")]
private static extern int getpid ();
```

From the dlopen(3) man page, the necessary shared libraries needed by the program are searched for in the following order:

1. A colon-separated list of directories in the user’s **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** environment variable. This is a frequently-used way to allow native shared libraries to be found by a CLI program.
2. The list of libraries cached in /etc/ld.so.cache. /etc/ld.so.cache is created by editing /etc/ld.so.conf and running ldconfig(8). Editing /etc/ld.so.conf is the preferred way to search additional directories, as opposed to using LD_LIBRARY_PATH, as this is more secure (it’s more difficult to get a trojan library into /etc/ld.so.cache than it is to insert it into LD_LIBRARY_PATH).
3. /lib, followed by /usr/lib.

More details can be found here [library handling](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/)

**edit:**

DllImport will fail if `libc.so` contains any unresolved symbols. Please verify with

```
ldd -r -d libc.so
```

and make sure no unresolved symbols are present there.