# Unable to load shared library in .NET Core in Linux (EntryPointNotFoundException)

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, shared-libraries, dllimport

I am working on .NET Core project (FooNC) that load shared library in Ubuntu (.so).
It is successful to load dll in Windows environment with DllImport

However, In Linux environment, it fails with:

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'FooFunc' in shared library libFoo.so
```

Test case:

```
dotnet ./FooNC.dll
```

I have a .NET Core project with such codes:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace FooNC
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("libFoo.so")]
        public unsafe static extern void FooFunc(); // only Linux related codes are shown

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FooFunc();
        }
    }
}
```

And a linux C++ project (compiled as shared library .so, via WSL in Windows)

main.h

```
#pragma once
void __attribute__((visibility("default"))) FooFunc(); // only Linux related codes are shown
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"
#include <cstdio>
void FooFunc()
{
    printf("FooFunc\n");
}
```

I verified in the Linux environment:

```
$ nm -CD ./libFoo.so | grep 'T '
0000000000001190 T FooFunc()

$ nm -D ./libFoo.so | grep 'T '
0000000000001190 T _Z13FooFuncv

$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
:/home/myacct/project

$ pwd
/home/myacct/project
```

Edit:
If I edit the code to be such, it will work, but I wonder, is there a way for C# side to "demangle" the symbol name?

```
[DllImport("libFoo.so", EntryPoint="_Z13FooFuncv")]
public unsafe static extern void FooFunc();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Above is edited with @DavidHeffernan hint.

These posts are related:

[Is there a Linux equivalent of DllImport in .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622375/is-there-a-linux-equivalent-of-dllimport-in-net-core)

[Explicitly exporting shared library functions in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164827/explicitly-exporting-shared-library-functions-in-linux)

Comment: Inspect the so file and list its exported function names to see whether a function with that name is exported.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks, I updated above and tried DllImport with "EntryPoint" and it will work. I now wonder, how can we make DllImport to resolve/demangle symbol name automatically? We have hundreds of functions to import and hardcoding the "EntryPoint" is not feasible

Comment: I think you could use extern "C" but you might be better scripting a solution to put the mangled names in your C# code. Then again I guess if you want support different compilers compiling the unmanaged code then they tend to have different mangling rules.